# Coerce Moment/Date to string with AJV

Tags: ajv

How can I coerce an json object that uses moment/date for date fields into a schema that uses 
`{type: "string", format: "date-time"}` with AJV?

I've tried using a custom keyword, but this doesn't run if the data is not a string.

```
{
  myDate: moment()
}
```

Should convert to

```
{
  myDate: "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could post an example of what you're trying to validate.

Comment: Updated to include example conversion